# Можно установить приоритет сборки jar файлов, в многомодульном проекте файле без использования зависимостей?

Tags: maven

Я хочу использовать:maven-war-plugin
предварительно скопировав в директорию lib все необходимые jar-ки, которые также собираются модулями. Файлы копируются, но не попадают в итоговый war, видимо копируются после сборки последней.

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.2</version>
<configuration>
<packagingIncludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingIncludes>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Если не использовать профили (или в каждом из профилей указать все модули), то сборка идет по прядку их (модулей)  задания в pom файле. Однако появилась новая проблема, в рамках задачи которую я пытался решить: jar-ки копируются в папку lib, но при повторном запуске из папки lib их приходится удалять вручную, иначе вне зависимости от профиля все эти  jar файлы попадут в war-ку. Может кто знает как очистить папку один раз (вначале) при запуске многомодульного приложения?

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема была в том, что я пытался чистить папку в начале цикла из родительского pom файла указав одну из maven фаз, но фазы в процессе выполнения повторяются для каждого jar файла предка и тем самым постоянно выполнялась чистка папки. Поместив чистку папки с помощью maven-clean-plugin в war файл (который собирается последним) и указав фазу install я решил проблему, папка чистится после сборки и готова для нового запуска.

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <configuration>
    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
    <dependentWarIncludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar,WEB-INF/classes/**</dependentWarIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Итоговое решение